# Почему не работает логический оператор 'and'

Tags: python

Я только начал изучать Python и есть вопрос по логическому оператору 'and'. Почему он не срабатывает в моем коде? Вроде синтаксис верный.
Задача про шахматную доску: Заданы две клетки шахматной доски. Если они покрашены в один цвет, то выведите слово YES, а если в разные цвета — то NO. Программа получает на вход четыре числа от 1 до 8 каждое, задающие номер столбца и номер строки сначала для первой клетки, потом для второй клетки.
'''

```
a = int(input())
b = int(input())
c = int(input())
d = int(input())
if ((a + b) % 2 == 0) and ((d + c) % 2 == 0):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

'''

В итоге я задачу решил, но так и не понял в чем была ошибка и почему условие if ((a + b) % 2 == 0) and ((b + c) % 2 == 0): не срабатывало.

Answer (score 1):

Что-то я не вижу, как в Вашем коде используется переменная `d`.

```
if ((a + b) % 2 == (c + d) % 2):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

или

```
if ((a + b + c + d) % 2 == 0):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

---

```
print(a,b,c,d)
print((a + b) % 2 == 0)
print((d + c) % 2 == 0)
print(((a + b) % 2 == 0) and ((d + c) % 2 == 0))
```

Comment: Игорь, спасибо! Замечание верное, это просто опечатка, но даже если использовать переменную d 'if ((a + b) % 2 == 0) and ((d + c) % 2 == 0)', задача решается не правильно

Comment: @Ilia Это неправильное условие. Я написал правильное. Может быть Вы скажете, какие у Вас входные данные?

Comment: в итоге я решил задачу также как и вы советуете. Но мне не понятно почему условие с 'and' не срабатывает? Ведь вроде все правильно написано и синтаксис верный. Входные данные a=1, b=1, c=2, d=6.

Comment: @Ilia Добавьте в код `print`ы, как показано в ответе, и посмотрите, что выведется.

Comment: Везде выводит True. Я понял свою ошибку. Ошибка была в написании, т.е не хватало еще одних скобок и в данное решение нужно дописать еще одно условие. Отлично!

Comment: @Ilia Очень хорошо. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.