# Как определить, покрашены ли две клетки шахмат в один цвет?

Tags: python, шахматы

Помогите с решением задачки. Не пойму, где моя ошибка в логике. Вот задача:

Заданы две клетки шахматной доски. Если они покрашены в один цвет, то выведите слово YES, а если в разные цвета – то NO. Вводятся 4 числа - координаты клеток.

Вот мое решение:

```
x = int(input())
y = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())
if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) and ((x2 + y2) % 2 == 0):
    print('YES')
else:
    print('NO')
```

Comment: код в соседнем вопросе взял? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1114331/%d0%9f%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80-and

Comment: нет, просто мыслили в одном направление

Answer (score 5):

А если обе суммы координат наоборот нечётные? :) Тогда уж так:

```
if (x + y) % 2 == (x2 + y2) % 2:
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно так

```py
if (x + y + x2 + y2) & 1:
    print('NO')
else:
    print('YES')
```

или так

```py
coords = [int(input()) for _ in range(4)]
print("NO" if sum(coords) & 1 else "YES")
```

или все в одну строку

```py
print(["YES", "NO"][sum(int(input()) for _ in range(4)) & 1])
```

или без `for`, с `map`

```py
print(["YES", "NO"][1 & sum(map(int, map(input, ['']*4)))])
```

А еще можно нахорить вместо сложения:

```py
if (x ^ y ^ x2 ^ y2) & 1:
```

Ну и можно использовать произвольные комбинации из `-`, `+`, `^`:

```py
if (x - y + x2 ^ y2) & 1:
```

Answer (score 1):

можно так

```
if (x + y + x2 + y2) % 2 == 0:
```